# How to put RadioButton that is in LineaLayout inside a RadioGroup

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I have six RadioButtons belonging to the same question, and I need to put them in some RadioGroup. But these RadioButtons is in some LinearLayouts. I tried to put one RadioGroup to each RadioButton, but i don't know what i need to do for it to work.

[image]

tab_layout_a.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <RadioButton
                                android:id="@+id/tipoPackRadio1"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Normal"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/radiobuttons_font_sz" />

                            <RadioButton
                                android:id="@+id/tipoPackRadio2"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Gilda"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/radiobuttons_font_sz" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.9"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <RadioButton
                                    android:id="@+id/tipoPackRadio3"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="Aged Pack \n(cheese/salve)"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/radiobuttons_font_sz" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                            <RadioButton
                                android:id="@+id/tipoPackRadio4"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Fellowship"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/radiobuttons_font_sz" />

                            <RadioButton
                                android:id="@+id/tipoPackRadio5"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Fertilizer"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/radiobuttons_font_sz" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.9"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <RadioButton
                                    android:id="@+id/tipoPackRadio6"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:text="Aged Pack \n(honey)"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/radiobuttons_font_sz"
                                    android:visibility="visible" />

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution..

```
   class MyActivity extends Activity {

RadioButton _Rone, _Rtwo, _Rthree;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//after setContentView(.....)

    _Rone = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_one);
    _Rtwo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_two);
    _Rthree = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_three);

    _Rone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            _Rone.setChecked(true);
            _Rtwo.setChecked(false);
            _Rthree.setChecked(false);
        }
    });

    _Rtwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            _Rone.setChecked(false);
            _Rtwo.setChecked(true);
            _Rthree.setChecked(false);
        }
    });

    _Rthree.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            _Rone.setChecked(false);
            _Rtwo.setChecked(false);
            _Rthree.setChecked(true);
        }
    });
 // do code here
}`
```

by clicking on anyradio button the other's selection will reset.

Comment: I cant do this, because i need the LinearLayouts

Comment: @KeltonHolandaFontenele This code will work with any type of layout. It only accesses RadioButtons directly.

Comment: Yes and *AnyLayout* does covers *LinearLayout*. So it should work. Just try and let me know

Comment: Really, this is so simple and i believe that it will work. Thanks a lot to help me! I will try now.

Comment: This works, thank you to all who took the time to help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... Cheers.